# In NodeJS, Is this the way I'm supposed to create responses to an HTTP server request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server

I'm trying to create a small app that shows different details of the user in base of the URL parameter "mod", like:

"Like http:/mysite?mod=overview" = returns an overview of the user's profile.

"http:/mysite?mod=friends" = returns the friend list of the user's profile.

"http:/mysite?mod=likes" = returns what the user liked.

And so on and so forth, I managed to get the logic going, like I can retrieve the info from the database, but I'm not sure if the way I'm programming it is correct, especially the fact that everything is managed by a switch inside the function passed to the "createServer" call. From what I've understood, it is the (only way I know) way to manage the creation of the response. So that's it? Are there alternatives? Is it "standard" or even, correct?

Am I on the right track?

That's my server:

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
 
const mymodule = require('./mymod');
 
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;
 
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => 
{
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    
  // Get URL params
  var query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
  
    // mod is "mode" like "http:localhost:3000?mod=overview"
    // it says what data to display and return to client
  if(query.mod != null)
  {
      // In this switch I manage every possible URL request?
      switch(query.mod)
      {
        case "overview":
          res.end('\nName: ' + query.name + "\nLevel: " + query.level + "\n\n"); // and so on
          break;
              
        // Here there will be many more cases that returns different things
         
        case "friends":
         res.end('\Your friends are: [...]"\n\n");
         break;
 
        case "likes":
         res.end('\Posts you liked: [...]"\n\n");
         break;
 
        // many other cases
 
        default:
          // default message
          res.end('\nHello World\nDate Time is: ' + mymodule.GetDateTime());
          break;
      }
  }
  else
  {
    // default message
    res.end('\nHello World\nDate Time is: ' + mymodule.GetDateTime());
  }
});
 
server.listen(port, hostname, () => 
{
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Comment: If you app gets more complex, you may benefit from a framework like [`express`](https://expressjs.com).

Comment: It's more usual to handle that with the path than with the query.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Thank you, I'm trying to do this simple app and I wanted to not use any other framework.

Comment: @Quentin could you give me an example on how to do it via path? But fundamentally, it should be the same thing, right?

Comment: Are you trying to manage the route or query string? @thePOOOISE

Comment: @DreamBold I'm just trying to understand how to manage the array of request a user can make and how to "grab" them in the Server code and return the correct response in base of the request.

In the code I posted above I do that with a switch case on the parameter "mod" of the URL, inside the function passed to the `http.createServer`. I'm just wondering if this is the correct approach to do that

Comment: Yes, you have to handle all and every request from the user and if the request is invalid, you can show the `404` page to the user. @thePOOOISE

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-web-server-in-node-js-with-the-http-module You can refer to this article as well

Comment: @DreamBold Perfect, so it's pretty standard to do it this way? There is no other way to "grab" a request other than inside the function passed to the `createServer` call, right? And from there you have to branch your code to make responses different for each different case, just like I did?

Comment: Exactly @thePOOOISE

Comment: @DreamBold Thank you! I'll give a good read to that tutorial you linked

Comment: Sure, and just let me know if you need anything else. Will be happy to help!